# change the background color of the Table Row

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-table

How can I change the background color of the Table Row, I tried using "BackgroundColor" but it didn't change

How can i solve the problem?

```
     <TableRow style={{ backgroundColor: "#FF0000" }}>
        <TableCell>
          <Button>All</Button>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
```

Comment: It does seems to work. https://codesandbox.io/s/basictable-material-demo-forked-72822j?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Are you just seeing the background color of a button? Could you put up your code into a runnable snippet so we can see for ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

try: background-color instead of backgroundColor

Never used react before, thats just the traditional css way.

Comment: no, this is material ui, in material ui we write backgroundColor not backgroun-color

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine. See below for a working example with your exact same attempt:

[image]

You can find the codesandbox reproduction [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hkbscu?file=/demo.tsx). You can also look into [the sx prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/) when working with MUI components.

Comment: i tried sx but the problem still found